# Tablet Application Development

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, tablet

I am going to start making a tablet application.

What is the difference between the layout of a mobile application and a tablet application?

If I am going to mimic a mobile application to a tablet application, how do I create the layout to suit the tablet layout?

What are the emulators that I can use apart from the default AVD offered by Android Studio, to test the tablet application?

This is my first tablet application, so what are the pre-requisites that I can keep in mind in order to develop the application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android you can combine a smartphone app with a tablet app, all you need is different layouts for the tablet. They will be placed in different subfolders of your resources folder. Assume you have a smartphone layout in the `res/layout` folder, tablet layouts will be placed in different folders representing the screensize and/or density. You will need `dimens.xml` for the different `dp` you use for the tablet layout, because smartphone `db` will be too small on tablet.

Use `sdp` library to create layouts that look the same on tablet and Smartphones. For an emulator I would prefer you Genymotion, it's free for personal use.

Answer (score 0):

Layout for tablet locate in res/layout-xlarge, so if you want create other layout for tablet - save one there. For testing i advise to use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)